# Calculated columns with given names can not be subtracted with those names in a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns, subtraction

Calculated columns with given names can not be subtracted with those names in a SQL query. Is there anyone who can tell me what the problem is?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MT.UnitNo
    ,UC.UnitName
    ,(SELECT (SUM(CAST(ISNULL(UnitPrice, '0') AS BIGINT)))
      FROM MonthlyUnitPrice MUP
      WHERE MUP.[Year] = '1398'
        AND MUP.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo) AS AnnualQuota
    ,(SELECT (SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalCalculatedPrice, '0') AS BIGINT)))
      FROM [ManagerTable] MTB
      WHERE MTB.[Year] = '1398'
        AND MTB.[Month] < '9'
        AND MTB.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo) AS TotalUsage
    ,(AnnualQuota - TotalUsage)
FROM 
    ManagerTable MT
INNER JOIN 
    UnitCodes UC ON UC.UnitNO = MT.UnitNO
INNER JOIN 
    MonthlyUnitPrice MU ON MT.UnitNO = MU.UnitNO
                        AND MT.[Year] = MU.[Year]
                        AND MT.[Month] = MU.[Month]
WHERE  
    MT.[Year] = '1398'
    AND MT.[Month] < 9
    AND MU.UnitPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    MT.UnitNo
    ,UC.UnitName
```

Errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'AnnualQuota'
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Invalid column name 'TotalUsage'

Comment: aliases can not be used in the same select clause.

Comment: You mean it is impossible to use aliases in this case?

Comment: The point is that I just want to avoid recalculating those columns for subtraction:`format((select(SUM(CAST(ISNULL(UnitPrice,'0') as bigint))) FROM  MonthlyUnitPrice MUP where MUP.[Year]='1398' and MUP.UnitNo=MT.UnitNo)-(select(SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalCalculatedPrice,'0') as bigint))) FROM  [ManagerTable] MTB where MTB.[Year]='1398'and MTB.[Month]<'9' and MTB.UnitNo=MT.UnitNo),'#,###,##0') as RemainingQuota`
 This one actually worked but I think it is not conventional.

Comment: The query optimizer of SQL-Server is probably clever enough to not recalc that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way [with acceptable performance] to calculate ratio :

```
With AnnualQuotaCTE as (
    SELECT
        SUM(UnitPrice) as TotalUnitPrice,
        UnitNo
    FROM MonthlyUnitPrice
    WHERE [Year] = '1398'
    Group by UnitNo

), TotalUsageCTE as (
    SELECT
        SUM(TotalCalculatedPrice) as SumTotalCalculatedPrice,
        UnitNo
    FROM [ManagerTable]
    WHERE [Year] = '1398' AND [Month] < '9'
    Group by UnitNo
)

SELECT 
    MT.UnitNo,
    UC.UnitName,
    AnnualQuotaCTE.AnnualQuota,
    TotalUsageCTE.TotalUsage,
    (Isnull(AnnualQuotaCTE.AnnualQuota, 0) - isnull(TotalUsageCTE.TotalUsage,0)) as UsageRatio
FROM ManagerTable MT
INNER JOIN UnitCodes UC ON UC.UnitNO = MT.UnitNO
INNER JOIN MonthlyUnitPrice MU ON MT.UnitNO = MU.UnitNO AND MT.[Year] = MU.[Year] AND MT.[Month] = MU.[Month]
LEFT JOIN AnnualQuotaCTE on AnnualQuotaCTE.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo
LEFT JOIN TotalUsageCTE on TotalUsageCTE.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo
WHERE MT.[Year] = '1398' AND MT.[Month] < 9 AND MU.UnitPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MT.UnitNo, UC.UnitName, AnnualQuotaCTE.AnnualQuota, TotalUsageCTE.TotalUsage
```

Also, you can add Year and Month to CTE and Main query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your query a lot:

```
SELECT MT.UnitNo, UC.UnitName,
       SUM(UnitPrice) as TotalUsage,
       AnnualQuota
       (AnnualQuota - SUM(UnitPrice)
FROM ManagerTable MT JOIN
     UnitCodes UC 
     ON UC.UnitNO = MT.UnitNO LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MUP.UnitNo, SUM(UnitPrice) AS AnnualQuota
      FROM MonthlyUnitPrice MUP
      WHERE MUP.[Year] = '1398'
      GROUP BY MUP.UnitNo
     ) MUP
     ON MUP.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo
WHERE MT.[Year] = '1398' AND
      MT.[Month] < 9
GROUP BY MT.UnitNo, UC.UnitName;
```

If you need the conversion to `BIGINT`:

```
SELECT MT.UnitNo, UC.UnitName,
       SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, UnitPrice)) as TotalUsage,
       AnnualQuota
       (AnnualQuota - SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, UnitPrice))
FROM ManagerTable MT JOIN
     UnitCodes UC 
     ON UC.UnitNO = MT.UnitNO LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MUP.UnitNo, SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, UnitPrice)) AS AnnualQuota
      FROM MonthlyUnitPrice MUP
      WHERE MUP.[Year] = '1398'
      GROUP BY MUP.UnitNo
     ) MUP
     ON MUP.UnitNo = MT.UnitNo
WHERE MT.[Year] = '1398' AND
      MT.[Month] < 9
GROUP BY MT.UnitNo, UC.UnitName
```